# Arduino SPI connector vs D11, D12, D13 pins

Tags: arduino

I have a problem with an arduino mega. I am playing with an SPI Bus.

If a connect MOSI to D11 pin, MISO on D12 and D13 on SCK, it does not work.

BUT, if i connect MOSI, MISO and SCK on the small connector (6 pins next CPU), everything works !

I do not understand why this 6 pins connector is connected to SPI whereas D11-D12-D13 are not connected.

Is there something to do (hardware/software) in order to activate spi bus on D11-D12-D13 pins ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [official Arduino SPI reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI), you are using the wrong pins for **Arduino Mega**:

- pin 51 or ICSP-4: MOSI
- pin 50 or ICSP-1: MISO
- pin 52 or ICSP-3: SCK
- pin 53                 : SS (slave)

Pins 11, 12 and 13 are used for **Arduino Uno, 101, Duemilanove**.

---

I conclude with two observations:

- the **ICSP** header, shown in the following picture, is consistent among all boards.
  [image]
- the board connections operate at different voltage levels, so it always a good idea to check the documentation before connecting any cable